# Как отрисовывать только видимую часть карты?

Tags: android

Хочу сделать простое приложение, которое будет отрисовывать простенькую карту (точнее схему) привязанную к реальным географическим координатам. Карту рисую с помощью SurfaceView и Canvas. Проблема в том, что при большом увеличении приходится отрисовывать многое "за кадром".

Приведу пример. Например, есть одна длинная прямая линия длиной 50 километров. Допустим, на этом масштабе у нас на один километр приходится 1000 пикселей. Таким образом, чтобы отрисовать эту линию я вынужден нарисовать линию длиной 50000 пикселей. В то время, как например Canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight() возвращает 32766 на моем устройстве, что явно меньше 50000.

Получается, нужно рисовать только видимую часть. Для этого надо либо каким-то образом высчитывать координаты только видимого отрезка из всей длинной линии, либо рисовать все, а потом обрезать. В первом случае, непонятно как высчитать, а во втором,непонятно существуют ли какие-то средства для этого.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно (и скорее всего надо) сделать фиксированный размер вашего View и отслеживать жесты на нем, по жестам определять какая часть карты будет видна. Для отображения карты надо ее разбить на небольшие участки, чтобы можно было всегда подгружать примерно одинаковое количество изображений и в следствии это поможет избежать OOM. Можно еще использовать DecodeRegion и декодировать из всего изображения только нужную часть. Вот как для примера можно посмотреть как реализовано отображение плитками. https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

Comment: А не подскажете, как можно разбить, например, длинную линию на несколько маленьких кусочков? Вероятно, это делается как-то математически?
DecodeRegion, вероятно, не подойдет. У меня ведь есть только набор координат в текстовом виде и все нужно отрисовать динамически, т.е., готового рисунка нет.

Comment: Я думал у вас готовая картинка. Если вы карту рисуете програмно, то можно просто рисовать используя cliprectangle. Если хотите определять какие элементы попадают в область видимости и рисовать их, то используйте сначала какой-нибудь алгоритм разбиения типа quadtree.